# Same ID, different lines, same value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for a way to find IDs that have a particular value more than once in different lines. For instance I'd have the following results:

```
ID   | LINES | PCODE
-----+-------+------
111  |   1   | 0450
111  |   2   | 0450
555  |   1   | 0450
677  |   1   | 0450
677  |   2   | 0450
677  |   3   | 0450
```

But what I'd actually want would be this:

```
ID   | LINES | PCODE
-----+-------+------
111  |   1   | 0450
111  |   2   | 0450
677  |   1   | 0450
677  |   2   | 0450
677  |   3   | 0450
```

I want all the IDs that use the 0450 Pcode in more than 1 line for that particular ID. There will be plenty of IDs with the 0450 Pcode but I just want the IDs that have them occur in several instances on different lines. I hope you can help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code, along with any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, however, perhaps:

```
WITH Counts AS (
    SELECT ID,
           LINES,
           PCODE,
           COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS LineNum
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE PCODE = '0450')
SELECT ID,
       LINES,
       PCODE
FROM Counts
WHERE LineNum > 1;
```